# How do I gain reputation points (without being a burden)?

Tags: discussion, support

I often come here to find answers to issues I'm having, and find what I need. Occasionally, I want to comment on an answer to clarify something that was only partially accurate, was missing some information, or to add other helpful info that I found in resolving the issue the question is about. However, I don't have enough reputation points to comment yet. Well, my problem with the current method of gaining reputation is this:

- question is voted up: +5 //I need to ask more questions, but don't have any right now because I often figure stuff out myself by Googling.
- answer is voted up: +10 //Don't have enough coding skills to answer most stuff yet, since I only know a fair amount about Max/MSP, and am just a beginner in C++ and Java.
- site association bonus: +100 on each site (awarded a maximum of one time per site) //No other profiles with enough points.

Also, I know about submitting suggested edits to answers. But then those require peer review, and may never be accepted and clarify/improve the answer.

Ultimately, I understand the reasoning behind not allowing comments without a rep of 50 (avoiding spam). But for legitimate users who want to help improve upon answers without adding more "answer spam" to the question, commenting on the top answer seems to be the best way of adding clarification that is more likely to actually be seen than an edit pending peer review.

So, since I don't know enough about code to answer anything I've come across yet that isn't already answered, the questions I have asked barely received any upvotes, and since approved edits get you so few points that gaining another 40 points that way seems like it would take ages, how can I up my rep without posting a bunch more questions that have most likely already been asked and answered by other users?

Comment: You listed all the ways to gain rep already. Honestly not sure what you are expecting more. And 20 edits to be approved is FAR from ages. 2, 3 days max (way less probably)

Comment: Ask good questions, give good answers, make correct edits. The purpose of the site is programmer assistance not earning reputation. Do good things and you will be rewarded. Yes, it may take time but 50 rep points comes in no time.

Comment: One more important skill that is very rare nowdays is to know of existence of search engines and the like... I.e. even if you can't use Google/Bing/other non-SE services just using local search frequently gives good results. I.e. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=start+novice brings very good post on meta (which I picked as duplicate).

Answer (score 6):

> Also, I know about submitting suggested edits to answers. But then those require peer review, and may never be accepted and clarify/improve the answer.

Get your edits accepted:

- Don't edit bad questions. You may get reputation if people approve the review but chances are the question is then deleted and your reputation will be gone for that edit. Flag these instead.
- Don't edit for the sake of editing. Only edit if you are making the post better.

You would be surprised by the amount of questions that are not formatted well, have links to pictures, hard to understand due to spelling, etc, etc.